# Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any[]>'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire5

I'm new with Angular and Firebase, I'm trying to get all of my items of a node to an AgularFireList, but I get this error:

Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type '{}[]'.

My code is:

```
my_notes: AngularFireList<any[]>;

constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getNotes()
      .subscribe(
        notas => {
          this.my_notes = notas;
        }
      );
  }

  getNotes(){
    return this.afDB.list('/notas').valueChanges();
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And please don't tag questions related to 2.x+ versions of `Angular` as `angularjs`.The later is reserved for 1.x versions of the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
this.getNotes()
  .subscribe(
    (notas: AngularFireList<any[]>) => {
      this.my_notes = notas;
    }
  );
}
```

If the issue still persists, try also adding this bit of code:

```
getNotes(){
    return <Observable<AngularFireList<any[]>>>this.afDB.list('/notas').valueChanges();
  }
```